# Resize a Rectangle which is on an angle

Tags: c#, .net, resize, angle

I have a Rectangle which is an array of 4 Point structures.  It can be rotated in place on any angle (0 to 360 degrees) and will draw properly.

The user can also drag a corner to resize the rectangle.  For example, if they move the bottom-left point, it will also update the X coordinate of the upper-left point, and the Y coordinate of the lower-right point.  In this way, it will always be a rectangle no matter which point they move.

```
Points[point] = newValue;

switch (point)
{
    case TopLeft:
        Points[BottomLeft].X = newValue.X;
        Points[TopRight].Y = newValue.Y;
        break;

    case BottomRight:
        Points[TopRight].X = newValue.X;
        Points[BottomLeft].Y = newValue.Y;
        break;

    case BottomLeft:
        Points[TopLeft].X = newValue.X;
        Points[BottomRight].Y = newValue.Y;
        break;

    case TopRight:
        Points[BottomRight].X = newValue.X;
        Points[TopLeft].Y = newValue.Y;
        break;
}
```

Here I change any of the four points to the given input point (newValue), and then modify the linked points so that it stays a Rectangle shape.

However, I need to modify the above code to work if my rectangle is on an angle like this:

[image: http://thesaurus.maths.org/mmkb/media/png/Rectangle.png]

Sample code added here:

http://www.assembla.com/code/moozhe-testing/subversion/nodes/rotateRectangle

Comment: Added sample code to an SVN repository linked above.  It works except in certain conditions which I can't figure out how to isolate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 solutions. The first one theoretically works, but because of rounding, it ends up not working. I'll let the first solution there, but **the second one is the good one**.

In these samples, I'll call the 4 corners CornerA, B, C and D, named in a clockwise fashion. Let's say you're moving "CornerA" from a position `Point oldPoint` to position `Point newPoint`.

First solution :

1. Get the position delta
2. Do a projection of that delta on Side `sideAtoB` and add that vector to PointD.
3. Do a projection of that delta on Side `sideDtoA` and add that vector to PointB.
4. Set PointA to newPoint.

Second solution :

1. Get the vector linking the opposite corner to the moving corner's new position, let's call it "Diagonal".
2. Set B's position to "C + [Projection of Diagonal on sideAtoD].
3. Set D's position to "C + [Projection of Diagonal on sideAtoB].
4. Set PointA to newPoint.

Here is the code for that 2nd solution :

```
public class Rectangle
{
    // Obviously, one would need to assign values to these points.
    Point CornerA = new Point();
    Point CornerB = new Point();
    Point CornerC = new Point();
    Point CornerD = new Point();
    Dictionary<int, Point> points = new Dictionary<int, Point>();

    public Rectangle()
    {
        points.Add(0, CornerA);
        points.Add(1, CornerB);
        points.Add(2, CornerC);
        points.Add(3, CornerD);
    }

    public void MoveAPoint(int id, Point newPoint)
    {
        // Get the old point
        Point oldPoint = points[id];
        // Get the previous point
        Point pointPrevious = points[(id + 3) % 4];
        // Get the next point
        Point pointNext = points[(id + 1) % 4];
        // Get the opposite point
        Point pointOpposite = points[(id + 2) % 4];
        // Get the delta (variation) of the moving point
        Point delta = newPoint.Substract(oldPoint);

        // I call sides points, but they are actually vectors.
        // Get side from 'oldPoint' to 'pointPrevious'.
        Point sidePrevious = pointPrevious.Substract(oldPoint);

        // Get side from 'oldPoint' to 'pointNext'.
        Point sideNext = pointNext.Substract(oldPoint);

        // Get side from 'pointOpposite' to 'newPoint'.
        Point sideTransversal = newPoint.Substract(pointOpposite);

        PointF previousProjection;
        PointF nextProjection;

        if (sideNext.X == 0 && sideNext.Y == 0)
        {
            if (sidePrevious.X == 0 && sidePrevious.Y == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            sideNext = new PointF(-sidePrevious.Y, sidePrevious.X);
        }
        else
        {
            sidePrevious = new PointF(-sideNext.Y, sideNext.X);
        }

        Point previousProjection = Projection(delta, sidePrevious);
        Point nextProjection = Projection(delta, sideNext);

        pointNext.SetToPoint(pointNext.AddPoints(previousProjection));
        pointPrevious.SetToPoint(pointPrevious.AddPoints(nextProjection));
        oldPoint.SetToPoint(newPoint);
    }

    private static Point Projection(Point vectorA, Point vectorB)
    {
        Point vectorBUnit = new Point(vectorB.X, vectorB.Y);
        vectorBUnit = vectorBUnit.Normalize();

        decimal dotProduct = vectorA.X * vectorBUnit.X + vectorA.Y * vectorBUnit.Y;
        return vectorBUnit.MultiplyByDecimal(dotProduct);
    }
}

public static class ExtendPoint
{
    public static Point Normalize(this Point pointA)
    {
        double length = Math.Sqrt(pointA.X * pointA.X + pointA.Y * pointA.Y);
        return new Point(pointA.X / length, pointA.Y / length);
    }

    public static Point MultiplyByDecimal (this Point point, decimal length)
    {
        return new Point((int)(point.X * length), (int)(point.Y * length));
    }

    public static Point AddPoints(this Point firstPoint, Point secondPoint)
    {
        return new Point(firstPoint.X + secondPoint.X, firstPoint.Y + secondPoint.Y);
    }

    public static Point Substract(this Point firstPoint, Point secondPoint)
    {
        return new Point(firstPoint.X - secondPoint.X, firstPoint.Y - secondPoint.Y);
    }

    public static void SetToPoint(this Point oldPoint, Point newPoint)
    {
        oldPoint.X = newPoint.X;
        oldPoint.Y = newPoint.Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the Normalize extension is supposed to be doing?  The function returns "new Point()" which should always be 0,0.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Assuming that you meant the Normalize() function to normalize the vector by dividing the vector x,y by the length, I have been able to get this to work however I do not know how to handle when the length is 0.

Comment: lol, yes, it's supposed to transform the vector into a unit vector. My bad, I just wanted to remove the red in my VS :-P

Comment: This works to an extent but I think there needs to be some error-checking for edge cases.  Right now I am drawing lines between the four points, and I can click on any point to resize the rectangle.   But generally if I cross-over the vectors by dragging one point through another, sometimes the whole thing gets distorted.  Are there conditions I can test such as equality/inequality/zero values of the delta, projection, or sides to avoid this?

Comment: What might be happening COULD be related to the rounding issues of using Point I was talking about. If your project ain't too big, I wouldn't mind to take a look and try to fix it. If you want to, just put it on a temporary free host online and post the url here.

Comment: I uploaded a simple project to http://www.assembla.com/code/moozhe-testing/subversion/nodes/rotateRectangle  I am thinking what I need to do in the MovePoint function is to check for erroneous conditions and just abort the operation without modifying the points structure in those cases.  This way, the client will continue to send MovePoint requests as the mouse keeps moving, it just won't complete them with erroneous data.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see what you mean. I'll edit the answer with something I tested with your code.

Comment: Why are you using a `Dictionary` like it's an array? It seems like your field declarations and constructor can be replaced by `Point[] points = new Point[4];`.

Comment: The code works great!  I have no problems when I am moving around a point while they are on an angle.  But I do run into problems if I leave the rectangle on perfect integers and not rotated.  This is most likely because two points are in the exact same position and therefore that side is 0.  I should be able to add a simple check so that the minimum side width is always at least 1 pixel.  I am not sure how to do that in a way that works while it's rotated, but I'm not sure I have to since the same behavior hasn't come up while the rectangle is rotated.

Comment: Nope it's still messing up when I cross the opposite point if the points are not rotated.

Comment: @Gabe: That's not really relevant to the question so I didn't put any serious thought in this. I could have used an array, or even a list, but that's just accessory to the solution.

Comment: @Moozhe : I've found a solution, so I'll update my solution. However, if you stack the 4 points on one another, the "anchorPath.IsVisible(cursorPosition)" in the "OnMouseDown" will always return false so you won't be able to move the square again :-S

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much Tipx!  You're right about there still being a problem if I let the points overlap, but I was able to put in an easy check before each MovePoint request to keep it at a minimum size of at least 1 pixel in width/height.  Your solution works perfectly, I've been moving the points around wildly for about 5 minutes and can't get them to distort.  Thanks again!

Comment: No problems! I'll just remove the code from the answer that is specific to your code now :-)

Comment: Why did you assigned the values twice:D
        pointNext = pointOpposite.AddPoints(previousProjection);
        pointPrevious = pointOpposite.AddPoints(nextProjection);

        pointNext.SetToPoint(pointNext.AddPoints(previousProjection));
        pointPrevious.SetToPoint(pointPrevious.AddPoints(nextProjection));

Comment: @SaraSaeed: Yes, delta = newpoint - oldpoint. The second thing you saw was actually an error. I edited that code so often to find the right answer and I didn't notice that error. Thanks for these constructive feedbacks!

Answer (score 0):

I used a solution that calculates the intersection between perpendicular lines:

Given a rotated rectangle (NOT axis aligned) with points, A, B, C, and D, and a dragged point D1 (which is the new point dragged from D), the goal is to find the new points for C1 and A1. B is opposite of D and will not move.

To find C1 and A1, find the intersection of the lines with points D1, which intersect with AB and BC and that are perpendicular to lines AB and BC (right angle). Those intersections will give you the points C1 and A1. Since the lines are perpendicular to AB and BC, they will form the new rectangle. Use the linear equations to calculate the slopes, intercepts and reciprocal slopes, which will give you both lines needed to calculate the intersection between AB and D1A. Repeat for the other side to get the intersection between BC and D1C (Remember, for axis-aligned rectangles, the below is not necessary and much easier)

Solution:
Find the slopes, opposite reciprocal slopes, and y-intercepts of the lines AB and AC. And find the y-intercepts of the lines D1A and D1C. Then calculate the intersection to get x and plug x into the lienar equation of one of the lines to get y:

```
slope_AB = (B.y - A.y) / (B.x - A.x)
y_intercept_AB = B.y - slope_AB * B.x
reciprocal_slope_AB = -1 / slope_AB
y_intercept_AD1 = D1.y - reciprocal_slope_AB * D1.x
A1x = (y_intercept_AB - y_intercept_AD1) / (reciprocal_slope_AB - slope_AB);
A1y = (slope_AB * B1x) + y_intercept_AB;
```

Repeat above 6 calculations accordingly to get C1x and C1y